# Image not being deleted after actual deletion in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, mariadb

I am working on a project in which I am facing a problem with Profile image. I am using Windows 10 as a system and XAMPP (apache, mariadb, php) as a development tool.

I have created one `profile.php` page which simply shows user info and options for updating user information. When I want to display profile image, it will find the image in directory `path="../img/user/alvis.jpg"` and load it.

If I delete the `alvis.jpg` image from the directory, and I load the `profile.php` page then it will *still* display the image without any error.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser probably has that image cached.
In profile page make a check if image still exists. If not, display some default thumbnail.

Instead of alvis.jpg, use something unique when creating, updating profile images. For example, timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in Incognito Browser. Actually the image might be cached which is making the browser to load from local than from the actual source.

Just to be sure, check the names and path once again - In your code and in folders.